# When Creating Key To Generate Signed Apk I Am Getting Error keytool error

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool

When trying to create a new key to generate signed Apk in Android Studio I Am Getting Error:

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Key (Access is denied)

[image]

I also did search for answers on web but nothing help. Help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to select the keypath and enter key name[image]